# Build Phonegap Hydrated App Screen

Tags: android, cordova, build

I am creating a mobil project with phone gap. My project include few page tag in one index.html file. When I build my project without Hydration, all page are shown in main page on Galaxy Note 4. When I build with hydration, my project is shown normally. But when application starting, a page is showing ("Loading Hydrated Application"). I don't want to show this page. How can I close this page?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the only way to keep "Loading Hydrated Application" from showing is to build without Hydration enabled.

That being said, I had a similar problem with the PhoneGap Robot showing up on a brief splash screen as my app loaded on a mobile device.  I found the image somewhere in the 'www/res/' directory and changed it to my company logo.  Problem solved for me.

Perhaps there is a similar process happening for the Hydration message.  Try looking in the images to see if it is there, and if so, replace it with something more appropriate.